# Apache/PhantomJS seeing localhost as external IP

Tags: apache, networking, phantomjs

When creating a connection from PhantomJS to a domain hosted on the localhost the client IP is detected as the server external IP.

Apache is configured to have an `htpasswd`, and it is setup to allow local connections to bypass it. But in the error log I get:

```
[Mon May 27 10:23:31 2013] [error] [client 123.215.64.94] user  not found: /path/to/file
```

`123.215.64.94` is one of the servers external IP addresses.

The PhatomJS script is simply:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://mysite.com/path/to/file', function () {
    page.render('output.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

So how do I configure Apache to bypass the htpasswd (without having to put the servers external IPs in the Apache configuration)?

The apache config is:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/www-mysite/public
    <Directory /home/www-mysite/public>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        AuthUserFile /home/www-data/.htpasswd
        AuthName "Password Protected"
        AuthType Basic
        Order Deny,Allow
        Satisfy any
        Deny from all
        Require valid-user
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why don't you just connect to `http://localhost/path/to/file`?

Comment: @Blender because it is setup as a `VirtualHost` with a `ServerName`, i.e. there is multiple sites served on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be treated as an Apache, not a PhantomJS, question. To all intents and purposes "123.215.64.94" and "127.0.0.1" are the same person. Only someone on that same machine can access from "123.215.64.94".

So in your apache config you could change `Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1` into `Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 123.215.64.94`

Of course, this is a bad idea if this server configuration is used on more than one server; or if it is a short-lived cloud instance, and gets a new IP address each time. In that case using an environmental variable in the Apache config will be more stable.

Comment: Yea, not ideal, I did think of this. Might be the only way though. I also thought of just adding the domain name to the hosts file and redirect it to `127.0.0.1`.